# How do I improve battery life under Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, laptop, debian, battery

I have Sonny S series laptop(Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz)  with Debian testing on it with 3.10-3-amd64. I love Debian Gnu Linux, everything is great except that the battery life. I have win7 on the same laptop and its battery life is at least 2.5x times better than Debian.

I have 2 batteries on this unit. Under Windows this laptop survives over 4 hours no problem. But I am unable to get proper 1.5h juice under Debian

I have powertop installed. I try to enable the recommendation. I also use much dimmer screen.  I have laptop-mode installed. Still this battery life is so bad that I avoid taking my laptop outside unless I am willing to use win7 on it.

What are are the recommendations to match the Win battery performance?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will almost never get the same performance in battery life on Linux compared to Windows.

The main and most significant cause being the drivers.

In summary, Windows has many more developers that are paid to write Windows drivers. Linux on the other hand has practically no support for most hardware. Most Linux developers do not get paid.

OEM drivers are very commonly protected under some licence, and the source code is often proprietary. Many drivers cannot be used on Linux because of design or because of the GNU licence. Therefore, many of the Linux drivers are just reversed engineered from the OEM Windows drives and ported to Linux. This of course means less efficiency on the hardware, resulting in poor battery performance.

My recommendations are to look for OEM drivers for Linux and install those. These will most likely not be in the repositories. You may have to build them yourself as well.

For example, I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W520. It has two graphic cards, one for battery life, and the other being for performance. I've had to (until recently) use one or the other because the OEM manufactures only supported Windows. Within the past 6 months I was able to get drivers for Linux, but the turnout was a year and a half.

Comment: Hi thanks for your in depth reply. That is helpful but that does not directly address my question. You explained the issue well but no real solution offered.

Comment: This are no solutions for inefficient drivers other than using the OEM ones provided, or making your own. Unfortunately, this is one of the main reasons in companies using Windows over Linux - the support.